# Programmatically hide an application on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Is there a way to programmatically hide an application on windows? I want to achieve the same thing as the windows+D shortcut, but for a single application. I want to do this from within that application (application consists of several windows, one of those can't be moved, resized, closed or minimized by the user). Application is written in c++ and uses Qt for the UI.

Comment: [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) with SW_HIDE, you need store handles (HWND) of all your windows

Comment: Using SW_HIDE on all the application windows causes the application's icon to be removed from the task bar, so this is not an option. SW_MINIMIZE, as stated in another answer, does the trick however.

Answer (score 2):

to do so it's so easy:

1- retrieve the handle to that window:

```
HWND hChild = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_MYCHILD);
```

2- send to it SW_SHOW either using ShowWindow or via SendMessage:

```
ShowWindow(hChild, SW_HIDE); // hide
ShowWindow(hChild, SW_SHOW); // show

SendMessage(hChild, SW_HIDE, 0, 0); // hide
SendMessage(hChild, SW_SHOW, 0, 0); // show
```

- if the window doesn't belong to your application then:

1 - retrieve the main window with:

```
HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow(void);
```

2- use the above to hide/show it

Comment: Small typo in your second `ShowWindow`. I think you meant for it to read `SW_SHOW`

Comment: Using SW_HIDE on all the application windows causes the application's icon to be removed from the task bar, so this is not an option. SW_MINIMIZE, as stated in another answer, does the trick however.

Answer (score 1):

```
ShowWindow(HwndWindow, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Here's the [MSDN ShowWindow documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx).

In addition you may find [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) useful for finding all these windows if their handles aren't readily available to you.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks.