# Single Instance Form Application in Shortcut

Tags: c#

Im trying to set single instance in c#, when user close the application this hides and if user click on the shortcut the first instance will show up.

I've tried to execute SetForegroundWindow, etc..

How I can show the first instance if is running in background?

[Image of code when user close form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvUE.png)

[Program.cs instance control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf13W.png)

Comment: So how would you actually close the instance ? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to create a single-instance WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-wpf-application)

Comment: The instance when user close the form i use the Hide() funtion to hide, and create a notifyicon

Comment: I think you should split your question into smaller parts. The following question is related, but is only part of your problem: [Programmatically hide an application on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39897167/33499)